# Help me understand if discrete time signal is periodic or not?

Tags: signal-processing

I need help identifying if the following discrete-time signal is periodic or not.

\$ x[n] = \cos(9πn^2) \$

\$ \frac {W_0}{2\pi} = \frac {9\pi}{2\pi} \$  which is a rational number so this should be periodic.

But I don't think that's correct judging from the graphs of the function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show the graphs.

Comment: I've MathJAXed your equations for legibility. Please check that I haven't introduced any errors.

Comment: The phase increment from \$n=0\$ to \$n=1\$ is \$9\pi\$.  The phase increment from \$n=1\$ to \$n=2\$ is \$27 \pi\$.  In fact, for \$n \ge 0\$, the phase increment from \$n\$ to \$n + 1\$ is \$(2n + 1) 9 \pi\$.  Does the concept of a constant frequency, which you imply with your \$W_0\$, apply to this function?